# How can I write a link with multiple lines in Markdown?

Tags: html, markdown

Expect HTML:

```html
<a href="https://example.com"><p>line1</p><p>line2</p></a>
```

How can I write this in Markdown?

The following doesn't work.

```markdown
[line1

line2
](https://example.com)
```

Comment: Is there a specific flavor of Markdown you're using? If so, that specific flavor might break my answer. I tested my answer and it does work with vanilla markdown and GitHub flavored markdown.

Comment: thanks! I use GitHub flavored markdown. I prefer another answer using `\`, I don't want to import an HTML tag in Markdown. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need a backslash before your newlines:

```
[line1\
\
line2](https://example.com)
```

[line1



line2](https://example.com)

Answer (score 0):

Try inserting [line breaks(`br` tags)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/br) where you want multiple lines:

```markdown
[line1<br><br>line2](https://google.com)
```